# VBA declaration of private array crashes Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this declaration at the beginning of my code. I run macro, in Outlook 2010 32 bit, via button in ribbon.

```
Option Explicit
Private Map1(0 To 63) As Byte
Private Map2(0 To 127) As Byte
```

When the user tries to run macro the first time, Outlook crashes: Microsoft Outlook has stopped working. The workaround for this is to open the VBA editor and close. Then click to run macro and it works. When I remove those declarations, this error does not not occur.

Code which is run at beginning:

```
Option Explicit
Private InitDone  As Boolean
Private Map1(0 To 63)  As Byte
Private Map2(0 To 127) As Byte

Sub SDMC()
    ''' check if userform is already loaded '''
    If SDMC_IsUserFormLoaded("ufSDMC") Then Unload ufSDMC
    Load ufSDMC
    Call ufSDMC.SdmcForm
End Sub

Function SDMC_IsUserFormLoaded(ByVal ufname As String) As Boolean
    Dim uForm As Object
    SDMC_IsUserFormLoaded = False
    For Each uForm In VBA.UserForms
        If uForm.Name = ufname Then
            SDMC_IsUserFormLoaded = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

There are also functions which use those variables, but they are not run when macro is starting.

Comment: is that all the code?

Comment: Code added. This code is run at begining. It loads userform. Variables are used in functions whic can be run later. So I don't think they are the reason. They are to long to paste them here.

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Comment: Outlook 2010, 32-bit

Comment: Have you tried to only declare Map1 and 2 and them ReDim them?